# What is the equivalent of "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" on Windows when using things like Xming?

Tags: windows, xorg, sockets, xming

I want to know what exactly does the display name like `:0.0` **mean** on Windows. Where does Xming place its listener socket for others to find? When I set the "Display location" in PuTTY, where does it go to connect to it? What is the equivalent of a "unix domain socket" on Windows anyway?

Finally, who exactly sets the standard for how these displays are managed on Windows, and where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xming and PuTTY use TCP sockets on the loopback address; the empty host name equals `localhost`. The TCP port numbers allocated for X11 start at 6000 for display :0, 6001 for display :1 and so on.

This is not actually Windows-specific behavior – X has been originally designed as a TCP/IP protocol and used that way for decades, which is the reason 'xauth' and even the idea of an "X server" exist. So it is the natural fallback when local sockets are unavailable.

---

That said, Windows NT *has* close equivalents to Unix domain sockets. Named pipes on Windows are bidirectional and can be packetized. (However, while they have paths, they only exist in a virtual "pipefs" and not as real filesystem entries, so they're closer to Linux abstract namespace sockets than regular ones.)

Second, Windows 10 has actually added the same AF_UNIX socket type [in release 1803](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/), although probably no software uses it yet.

Libraries such as Cygwin or libassuan also emulate Unix sockets via loopback TCP, although not always in a compatible manner.